# String or binary data would be truncated => column name in script

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this table which contains these columns:

```
CREATE TABLE CARD
(
    CARD_IDE INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    CARD_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CARD_NUMBER NUMERIC(4) NOT NULL,
    CARD_COLOR VARCHAR(10),
    CARD_MANA_COST VARCHAR(30),
    CARD_MANA_CONVT VARCHAR(3),
    CARD_TYPE VARCHAR(50),
    CARD_POWER VARCHAR(2),
    CARD_TOUGH VARCHAR(2),
    CARD_RARTY VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    CARD_TEXT_ABILT VARCHAR(800),
    CARD_TEXT_FLAVR VARCHAR(800),
    CARD_ARTST_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    CARD_SET_IDE INT NOT NULL,
    CARD_FLAG_FACE INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CARD_CHILD_IDE INT
);
GO
```

The creation of the table itself does not pose any problems. We feed our primary data with scripts for testing purpose. However, the columns `CARD_FLAG_FACE` and `CARD_CHILD_IDE` were newly introduced as of this week, and they give me problems.

Here's the script we roll to feed our data:

```
INSERT INTO CARD (CARD_NUMBER, CARD_NAME, CARD_COLOR, CARD_MANA_COST, CARD_MANA_CONVT, CARD_TYPE, CARD_POWER, CARD_TOUGH, CARD_RARTY, CARD_TEXT_ABILT, CARD_TEXT_FLAVR, CARD_ARTST_NAME, CARD_FLAG_FACE, CARD_CHILD_IDE, CARD_SET_IDE)
SELECT 1, 'Angel of Glory''s Rise', 'White', '5WW', '7', 'Creature  - Angel', '4', '6', 'Common', 'Flying When Angel of Glory''s Rise enters the battlefield, exile all Zombies, then return all Human creature cards from your graveyard to the battlefield. ', '"Justice isn''t done until undeath is undone." ', 'James Ryman', 0, null, @CardSetIdForAVR
    GO
```

If we run this, I get the following error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 9
>   String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated.

The line 9 is the exact line of the `INSERT` statement, which puzzles me. Now if I run the same script while stripping the two new columns:

```
INSERT INTO CARD (CARD_NUMBER, CARD_NAME, CARD_COLOR, CARD_MANA_COST, CARD_MANA_CONVT, CARD_TYPE, CARD_POWER, CARD_TOUGH, CARD_RARTY, CARD_TEXT_ABILT, CARD_TEXT_FLAVR, CARD_ARTST_NAME, CARD_SET_IDE)
SELECT 1, 'Angel of Glory''s Rise', 'White', '5WW', '7', 'Creature  - Angel', '4', '6', 'Common', 'Flying When Angel of Glory''s Rise enters the battlefield, exile all Zombies, then return all Human creature cards from your graveyard to the battlefield. ', '"Justice isn''t done until undeath is undone." ', 'James Ryman', @CardSetIdForAVR
GO
```

Now it runs smoothly. I don't understand why the error occurs and I need your help.

**EDIT**

As per many request (and because I cannot find the errors) I have posted the original code.

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table? Most likely ths is the cause

Comment: What is a trigger? I'm not used with sql script, so I don't know what it is.

Comment: But, to be frank, I don't think there's a trigger as I've read most of the scripts and I haven't seen this command anywhere.

Comment: Ok, just wait everyone, there were errors in my first post and I will correct them.

Comment: OBJECT_RARITY is VARCHAR(1) and you send 'rare' both times. Vote to close. We do not have full details

Comment: As I already said, I'm not allowed to post the full code. This is identical to the original script. And I've modified the fields in error.

Comment: As written your edited script runs fine for me

Comment: Ok, I will check it out, maybe there was a typo in it.

Comment: I cannot find the error and to get further help I have posted the original code. Feel free to check it out.

Comment: @HerveS Checking it now

Comment: @HerveS check my updated answer.  You are passing `'common'` for rarity which is a varchar(1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a several issues here:

1 - Your column `OBJECT_WEAKNESS` is a `varchar(2)` but you are trying to put `'None'` in.  This could be causing your issue with truncation

2 - Your `CREATE TABLE` statement does not have a data type for your first column, so this is not executable code

3 - You need to escape the quotation mark in `Finely crafted to Salzman's specifications`

**EDIT:**

Your update with the actual code shows the issue pretty clearly:

```
CARD_RARTY VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL

'Common'
```

If I make this a `'C'` it works fine.

Comment: Yeah, you are right on those, those are typos I made while rewriting the script. I'm sorry. I will correct these at once.

Comment: Well if we don't have the actual code we can't help find the issue.

Comment: I'm not allowed to paste the actual code. It is a retranscription identical to the original code, just the name of the fields and data has been changed. Sorry.

Comment: I cannot find the error and to get further help I have posted the original code. Feel free to check it out.

Comment: Holy... that was it! You're right, somehow the app which job was to correctly write this script failed :) Well done, and many thanks!

Comment: @HerveS happy to help, but next time just show your actual code :)

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean, usually I try to be as loyal as possible to the code. This time I had to "ask" around to make sure it was okay though. Thanks again.